# Updating integers in a list by adding integers from another list to them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of integers `a` and `b`. I want to update the integers in `a` such that `a[i] = a[i] + b[i]`.

**Note: I want to avoid creating a new list. I want to update the existing list.**

Currently, I am doing it using a `for` loop as shown below.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [10, 10, 20, 20, 100]
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
...     a[i] += b[i]
...
>>> a
[11, 12, 23, 24, 105]
```

Can the `for` loop be replaced with a single-liner code that is equivalent to it?

Comment: I do not understand how this question of mine has been voted to be closed. I do not want to create a new list. Instead, I want to update an existing list.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done pretty simply with a comprehension:

```
[a_i + b_i for a_i, b_i in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: This creates a new list. However, I want to update an existing list.

Comment: Just assign the existing list this comprehension

Comment: Please provide working code.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple way would be to import numpy (if you have it installed, or will be doing similar things).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [10, 10, 20, 20, 100]
>>> a = np.add (a,b)
>>> a
array([ 11,  12,  23,  24, 105])
```

This and the original question run the risk of the array size differing. This method will always raise a ValueError if that happens. In the first, whether the error exposed depends on which list is shorter.

Comment: If you are using `numpy`, wouldn't it be easier to just make `a` and `b` ndarrays, and just do `a+b`?

Comment: If starting from lists, I think this is easier. An alternative would be to use np.arrays a and b. Then a = a + b would give the desired result. a = np.array ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])... etc.